# How the find the symtric difference between several arrays using filter and reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on library called [arrowjs](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/blob/master/src/1.x.x/scripts/array/difference.js).

I want to refactor the code of the `difference` function which finds the difference between multiple arrays.

After creating jest `tests` I find some `bugs` and currently I want t to work as the developer expects.

This function finds the difference between two arrays, however, it does not pass the test when the developer passes many arrays.

```js
// How to refactor this function to make diff between many arrays

    function diff(arr1, arr2) {
        return [
            ...arr1.filter((item) => !arr2.includes(item)),
            ...arr2.filter((item) => !arr1.includes(item)),
        ];
    }
```

```js
    console.log(diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // passed

    console.log(diff([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])); // failed

    console.log(diff(['diorite', 'andesite', 'grass', 'dirt', 'pink wool', 'dead shrub'],
    ['diorite', 'andesite', 'grass', 'dirt', 'dead shrub'])) // failed
```

**Unit Tests:**

```js
describe('Find different elements between many arrays', () => {
    it('should return an array with the uncommon elements between arrays ', () => {
        expect(diff([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])).toStrictEqual([4]);
        expect(diff(['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])).toStrictEqual(['c']);
        expect(
            diff([null], [undefined, null], [undefined, null, 'Ala'])
        ).toStrictEqual(['Ala']);
        expect(
            diff(
                ['diorite', 'andesite', 'grass', 'dirt', 'pink wool', 'dead shrub'],
                ['diorite', 'andesite', 'grass', 'dirt', 'dead shrub']
            )
        ).toStrictEqual(['pink wool']);
    });
    it('should return an empty array ', () => {
        expect(diff([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2])).toStrictEqual([]);
    });

    it('should return the original array ', () => {
        expect(diff([1, 2])).toStrictEqual([1, 2]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main question here is how we can provide an arbitrary number of arguments. You can do that with the spread operator:

```
function diff(...arrs) {
```

after that it's just a matter of handling more than the two previous arrays.
Using a naive/very similar algo with the original case of the two arrays, it could look something like

```
function diff(...arrs) {
  return arrs.flatMap((arr => {
    return arr.filter((item) => !arrs.filter(innerArrs => innerArrs !== arr).flat().includes(item))
  }));
}
```

but up to you on how to improve it

Comment: Tests passed. Perfect!